# Removing border from table cells

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I know this is a dumb question but I seem to have totally forgotten how to do it.

I have a HTML `table` and I want to remove all borders around all the  cells so that there is only one border around the entire table.

My code looks like:

```
<table border='1' width='500'>
  <tr><th><h1>Your Wheelbarrow</h1></th><tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just collapse the table borders and remove the borders from table cells (`td` elements).

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: none;
}
```

Without explicitly setting `border-collapse` cross-browser removal of table cell borders is not guaranteed.

Comment: FYI: If you specify `border-collapse: collapse` on the `table`, you don't need to specify `border: none` on the `td` element. It takes care of it.

Comment: Thanks the border-collapse attribute was missing in my styling, it works now!

Answer (score 17):

The HTML attribute for the purpose is `rules=none` (to be inserted into the `table` tag).

Comment: Is there a CSS alternative for that?

Answer (score 5):

Probably you just needed this CSS rule:

```
table {
   border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bz3Jt/3/

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
table {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: *Note that the `type` attribute is no longer needed.*

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QPKVX/

Not really sure what you want your final layout to look like- but that fixes the colspan problem too.

Answer (score 3):

Just use your table inside a div with a class (`.table1` for example) and don't set any border for this table in CSS. Then use CSS code for that class.

```
.table1 {border=1px solid black;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your table declaration to:

```
<table style="border: 1px dashed; width: 500px;">
```

Here is the sample in action: http://jsfiddle.net/kc48k/

Comment: Ok thanks that gives me a border just around the table but how can you also set the borders around the table rows??

Comment: Set `tr` to use a `style="border...` too. Or, alternatively, define a `<style>` section in the head of your page.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the solutions on this page work and you are having the below issue:

[image]

You can simply use this snippet of CSS:

```
td {
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @brezanac mentioned, you can add the border-collapse, no need for anything else. I attach and example

```css
.table {
    border: 1px solid #CCC; // only for example
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC; // only for example
 }
```

```html
<table aria-describedby="table without borders"
       class="table">
  <tr>
    <th id="id">id</th>
    <th id="name">name</th>
    <th id="price">price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pizza</td>
    <td>7.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Burger</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table aria-describedby="table with borders">
  <tr>
    <th id="id">id</th>
    <th id="name">name</th>
    <th id="price">price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pizza</td>
    <td>7.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Burger</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```