# Stuck with html table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create following table.[sample of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RpvR.png)

My Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>


td {
    border: none;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgColor="pink" link="red" text="black" link="blue" vlink="green" alink="blue">
        <center>
            <font color="red" size="6">
                    E-games
            </font>
        <br/>
            </center>
            <br clear="right" />
            E-GAMES is a website offering new and friendly games for all games
            <image align="right" src="games.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
            <br/>
                <b> Games Offered </b>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    Individual Games
                        <ul type="square">
                            <li> 
                                Spelling Bee 
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                Zuma Deluxe
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                Mario
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Group Games
                    <ul type="circle">
                            <li> 
                                Chess
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                Billiards
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                Snooker
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                </ol>
                <b>You can also buy CDs of following games through our site</b>
                <center>
                Price List
                </center>
            <table width="50%" align="center" border="2" bordercolor="blue" >
                
    
                <th> Game Name </th>
                <th> Price </th>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Spelling Bea
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rs. 200
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Billards
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rs. 300
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Snooker
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rs. 400
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to do this by nesting of tables in html. But it didn't work. Now I think this cannot be done without using css. You have to use CSS for this.
**What have I tried**

[Nested table](https://jkorpela.fi/html/cellborder.html#:%7E:text=For%20HTML%20tables%2C%20you%20can,border%20for%20the%20entire%20table.)

[Removing border from table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131729/removing-border-from-table-cells)

But so far I am unable to achieve the table shown in the sample image

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rojo does this question still more clarification. Do tell. I will add more details to it.

Comment: If you want an upvote or two, I'd recommend changing to title to a question rather than a statement. You should probably compare your current output to the expected output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just cell spacing

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks!. @epascarello. I really appriciate what you did.